# PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (zlib library version does not match - header: 1.2.11, library: 1.3) when deploying app to Railway

Tags: luatex

I currently have Django code that compiles a LaTeX file using lualatex. It works locally in my virtual environment, but when I deploy my project to Railway, I am getting the following error:

PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (zlib library version does not match - header: 1.2.11, library: 1.3)

I attempted to install zlib version 1.3 (and I also tried 1.2.11) manually with nixpacks in a railway.json file, but the error still persists when I try to compile a LaTeX file on my deployed web app. Here is my railway.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.up.railway.app/railway.schema.json",
  "build": {
    "builder": "NIXPACKS",
    "nixpacksPlan": {
      "phases": {
        "setup": {
          "aptPkgs": ["...", "texlive-full", "wget"],
          "cmds": [
            "wget https://zlib.net/current/zlib.tar.gz && tar -xzf zlib.tar.gz && cd zlib-1.3 && ./configure && make && sudo make install"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "deploy": {
    "startCommand": "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn layoutGenerator.wsgi",
    "restartPolicyType": "ON_FAILURE",
    "restartPolicyMaxRetries": 10
  }
}
```

and here is my requirements.txt created from my virtual environment:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==5.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
numpy==1.26.2
openpyxl==3.1.2
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.1.3
pdf2image==1.16.3
Pillow==10.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
```

Everything else seems to work on the web app other than this LaTeX compilation. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Installing zlib-1.3 definitely won't help: the error is stating that the luatex binary is linked to the 1.2.11 version of zlib, while the version found in your install is 1.3. You need to either downgrade zlib to 1.2.11 or install a TeX binary that is linked to zlib-1.3.

Comment: I don't know what the underlying distribution is that you are using with Railway, but this sort of version mismatch problem is often solved by your distro rebuilding texlive-bin to link against the current version of zlib. // Whatever you are using for texlive it is **really old**. zlib-1.2.**12** was released in March last year, so your tex binaries are more than 18 months old. This will almost surely break newer documents using the features incorporated in the Oct 2022 release of TeX.

Comment: [Debian stable](https://wiki.debian.org/TeXLive) is using still TeXLive 2022, which is probably part of the problem. Again, I know next to nothing about Railway.app, but I am tempted to guess (because it uses Nixpack), you are in a situation where you somehow ended up mixing incompatible versions of packages. (Incidentally, Nix does not have a maintainer for texlive, so their version is also out of date.) // I am pretty sure this is **not** a TeX problem technically speaking. Perhaps stackoverflow may be better.